# MKR ZERO is not detected in IDE / MKR ZERO not showing up in windows 8.1/

Tags: arduino-ide, windows, mkrzero

I m connect it with my IDE software and its work perfectly yesterday, but today morning I'm connected it to software to upload another sketch but its didn't detect the port and the charge led is not on yesterday but today is on. I tried every resolution which is given on website but its didn't work. please help me through this I'm new to this board.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the IDE not able to find the board despite it being clearly seen and selected?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/67020/why-is-the-ide-not-able-to-find-the-board-despite-it-being-clearly-seen-and-sele)

Answer (score 0):

A few possibilities come to mind:

1. Your USB cable is bad.  Try a known good one.
2. Your USB port has failed.  Try a different port or try plugging something else into this one to verify that it's still OK.
3. Your MKR ZERO has become damaged somehow.